# Is it possible to limit each filter in my query?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

My problem is an optimization of my query. Right now I have two queries added later. I would like to have only one query instead of them.   \

```
past_query = self.session.query(Event)\
        .filter(Event.start_date <= today)\
        .filter(Event.end_date <= today)\
        .limit(2)

future_query = self.session.query(Event)\
        .filter(Event.end_date >= today)\
        .limit(2)
```

I started to do something like my code below, but it is not the same.

```
q = self.self.session.query(Event)\
        .filter(or_(
            and_(
                Event.start_date <= today,
                Event.end_date <= today
            ),
            Event.end_date >= today)
        ).limit(4)
```

Is there a way to limit each filter by specific number? Thank you for your help.

Comment: can somebody help me?